# Start a program in VirtualBox with command prompt error

Tags: usb, drivers, virtualbox

I have a driver problem, the driver only works on 32 bit. I used XP mode but it isnt that good so I thought trying the same thing with virtual box in seamless mode.
Now when i try to start a process wit this command:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage guestcontrol test exec "C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe" --username Administrator
```

First he gave me the VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR but i fix that with changing the policy for accepting admin logins with no password
but now i get this error:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Concurrent guest process limit is reached.
```

Someone knows how to fix this?
(I'm using Windows 7 64 bit as host and Windows 7 32bit as guest)

Answer (score 1):

Just make a password for your admin. Then give the password with the command (dont forget to get the right user) and it will work.